# how to use auto hotkey to play my liked songs

Tags: autohotkey

i used this code

```
^+!l::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Spotify
{
    WinActivate
    Send, ^l
}
else
{
    Run, "C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"
    WinWait, Spotify
    WinActivate
    Send, ^l
}
return
```

but I keep getting errors like this code contains syntax errors function call requrs a space or ( only use a comma between parameters

i tried solving the problem with chat gpt but i keep getting erors i am on v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

^+!l::
{
    if WinExist("ahk_exe Spotify.exe")
    {
        WinActivate
        if WinWaitActive("ahk_exe Spotify.exe", , 2)
            Send "^l"
    }
    else
    {
        Run "C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"
        if WinWait("ahk_exe Spotify.exe", , 5)
        {
            WinActivate
            if WinWaitActive("ahk_exe Spotify.exe", , 5)
            {   
                Sleep 2000
                Send "^l"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get familiar with AutoHotkey, read the [Beginner Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Tutorial.htm).

Comment: thanks it works but it doesn't play my liked songs

Comment: Does the programm have a hotkey for playing the liked songs?